# Rest api returns "Network connection Failure" in chrome but working fine in firefox

Tags: angularjs, rest, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, cors

Maximum time my rest api fails and some times it works in chrome but it always works in firefox.
when calling api old data is coming in response.
Cors is also enabled with proper rule.
As per my observation it started happening after recent chrome update on 2nd sept,2017.

Technology used :- **Java,Angularjs**

Below is the error I get when api fails :-
`XMLHttpRequest` cannot load . Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested resource. Origin  is therefore not allowed access. The response had `HTTP status code 403.`

Get Api code :-

```
 executeGet: function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
    url: REST_API.SERVICE_BASE_URL + encodeURI(this.restURI),
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 2000,
    cache: false,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then(function (response) {
    deferred.resolve(response.data, response.status, response.headers, response.config);
    $log.debug( 'URL - '+ url_called, response.data, response.status);
  },function (response) {
    deferred.reject(response.data, response.status, response.headers, response.config);
    $log.debug( 'URL - '+ url_called, response.data, response.status);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
},
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **My rest api fails and some times it works in chrome**.   All doctors please come here for a ***Critical surgery***. :'( :'(

Comment: *“HTTP status code 403”* indicates an authentication failure. So when that  happens, check the server logs on the server which sent that 403 response to you, and go in and see why that 403 failure occurred in that case and not in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it's impossible to help you from this description. It's nothing to do with being a REST API, and it seems likely that the Chrome vs Firefox thing is just a coincidence.

To find out the cause of this missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` you need to debug your application like you would anything else. This can be done in a few ways.

You can enable New Relic or Data Dog to try to catch errors and other debugging information in an intelligent form, you can use Papertrail, Logentries, etc to see a trail of logs, you can use Rollbar to see just exceptions being fired if that's a bit cheaper than New Relic.

It's very likely that some error is being triggered (validation, auth, something) which is making your application return early, and it's not triggering whatever layer handles CORS. I can't take any guesses at what that might be because you've just put "Java" and we dunno if its Spring, something else or custom.

Best of luck with your debugging!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, where it was working via Chrome but not when accessing through AngularJS. I was using Spring boot on server side. The solution in my case was to enable Allowing CORS on the server side. In Spring you can enable using WebMvcConfigurer. [WebMvcConfigurer enabling CORS](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Comment: CORS is already enabled on server side. I have mentioned in my question description. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install in Chrome the extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi
and enable the cros origin resources

Comment: Should I tell my thousands of customer to install this exentsion. Not at all a proper solution. CORS is already enabled. :)